# Stop images overflowing container div

Tags: css

I have created a page with a fixed width column on the right that contains thumbnail images, and large images are displayed to the left. I currently use a Javascript function to limit the height of the `#thumbcontainer` div to the size of the window so that the `#thumbcolumn` div can scroll within if the number of thumbnail images exceed the height of the window.

However, I am thinking there must be a way to do this using CSS. The problem is that the images contained in `#thumbcolumn` don't stick to the height of the window and scroll - instead they expand beyond the window's height so that the whole window has to be scrolled down.

Here is the code:

```
<div class="imgcntnr">
   <div id="displayimages">
      <span style="white-space: nowrap;" id="imageset">various images</span>
   </div>

   <div id="thumbcontainer">
        <div id="thumbcolumn"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
.imgcntnr {
  padding: 10px 100px 0 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%
}

#displayimages,
#thumbcolumn {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}

#displayimages {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  padding-bottom: 3px;
}

#thumbcontainer {
  height: auto;
}

#thumbcolumn {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-right: -100px;
}

.thumbimages {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto 5px;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you use something like

```
.thumbnailcontainer
{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right:0;
    width: 200px;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

That should, in theory, give you a container that spans top to bottom of the window and scroll when the image list becomes to big.

EDIT: Example: http://jsfiddle.net/QgY3L/

Comment: Although, looking at the link you posted with the site it might be best to change the position:fixed to position:absolute and make its parent container relative.

Comment: Thanks. It is scrolling now but spans the entire height of the window

Comment: Change it to position absolute instead and make the parent container, position relative and see how that works.

Comment: Just tried your last comment and it's dissapeared completely!

Comment: Hmm strange, did you make class="imgcntnr" 'position:relative'?

Comment: Ahh, did the wrong one. That works nearly perfectly now thanks. The only thing wrong is the thumbcontainer is ignoring the padding I applied to the imgcntnr container

Comment: Is it missing the 100px padding on the right hand side? If it is then change right:0; to right:100px;

Comment: No it's the padding-bottom:10px of imgcntnr. It seems to be ignoring that.

Comment: Using 'position:absolute;' takes the container out of the current flow of elements so you can do one of two things to get the padding at the bottom. Either apply padding directly to the thumnbnail container or adjust 'bottom:0;' to 'bottom:10px;'. Either one of those should fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `overflow: scroll;` on `#thumbcolumn`.

Comment: Could you provide a live example of the page? Because I just tried your code in chrome/OSX and it seemed to work just as you wanted it to work.

Comment: Hm... Since you are using javascript to load the images you can probably instead set the height of the #thumbcolumn container based on viewport height in your thumbs() function to get the expected behaviour. Because as soon as you explicitly set a height (not 100%) on #thumbcolumn you will get the expected result with a scroll bar.